# Subset sum exponential solution - how does the sorting work?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, subset-sum

The wiki for the subset sum problem found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) it states that you take the list of N elements and split it into two lists of N/2 elements.  You then generate all the subsets for each list (each having $2^{N/2}$ subsets).  It then states...

"Each of these two lists is then sorted. Using a standard comparison sorting algorithm for this step would take time $O(2^{N/2}N)$. However, given a sorted list of sums for k elements, the list can be expanded to two sorted lists with the introduction of a (k + 1)st element, and these two sorted lists can be merged in time $O(2^{k})$."

Can someone illustrate/explain this part of the algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that two sorted lists of length $n$ can be merged into one sorted list of length $2n$ in time $O(n)$. This is a standard procedure used in the mergesort algorithm. Given a list of integers $x_1,\ldots,x_m$, you proceed as follows:

- Start with $A_0 = 0$.
- Merge $A_0$ and $A_0 + x_1$ into $A_1$.
- Merge $A_1$ and $A_1 + x_2$ into $A_2$.
- ...
- Merge $A_{m-1}$ and $A_{m-1} + x_m$ into $A_m$.
- Output $A_m$.

Here $A_k + x_{k+1}$ is formed by adding $x_{k+1}$ to all elements of $A_k$, preserving the order.

Since $A_k$ has length $2^k$, the total running time is
$$
O(|A_0| + |A_1| + \cdots + |A_{m-1}|) = O(1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^{m-1}) = O(2^m).
$$

Comment: What seems unclear is not the merging but the sorting.  To sort a list with  N elements (using mergesort) requires N $\log_2(N)$ steps.  We have $2^{N/2}$ elements (in each list).  Wouldn't performing merge sort on these elements take $2^{N/2}\log_2(2^{N/2})$ = $2^{N/2}*N/2$ steps?  This would imply a runtime of $O(2^{N/2}N)$ would it not?

Comment: We’re not using mergesort at all, only the linear time merge subroutine. The output array $A_m$ is already sorted.

Comment: I understand that merging 2 sorted lists of size N is O(N) but how do the lists (each of length $2^{N/2}$) get sorted to begin with then?  

From the wiki article is seems like the algorithm A-takes list of N elements, breaks it into two lists of N/2 elements.  B-generates all $2^{N/2}$ subsets for each list.  C-sorts these lists (how?) . D-merges these lists (each with $2^{N/2}$ elements) in linear time...which in this case is $O(2^{N/2})$

Comment: I suggest ignoring Wikipedia and focusing on my answer, which describes explicitly the linear time algorithm that outputs the sorted list of all subset sums.